# tt_news - where is the register "newsMoreLink" be defined?

Tags: function, typo3, typoscript, tt-news

The extension tt_news is very useful for me but there is this little thingy called "register:newsMoreLink". This register does contain the singlePid of the contentelement (defined a single view page) and the uid of the newsarticle from the news extension.

This is the typoscript section of the "new ts" of the extension tt_news
As you can see there is "append.data = register:newsMoreLink"...

```
plugin.tt_news {
displayLatest {
subheader_stdWrap {
# the "more" link is directly appended to the subheader
      append = TEXT
  append.data = register:newsMoreLink
      append.wrap = <span class="news-list-morelink">|</span>
      # display the "more" link only if the field bodytext contains something
      append.if.isTrue.field = bodytext
      outerWrap = <p>|</p>
}
}
}
```

What is "register:newsMoreLink"? Is this like a function or something? I do not know. But "register:newsMoreLink" produces a strange link if I use this on "append.data". It produces are "More >" link. The "More >" *link* after a news article teaser looks like this:

> http://192.168.1.29/website/index.php?id=**474**&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=**24**&cHash=95d80a09fb9cbade7e934cda5e14e00a

474 is the "singlePid" (this is what it calls in the database
24 is the "uid" of the news article (the ones you create with the tt_news plugin in the backend)

My question is: Where is the "register:newsMoreLink" defined? Is it defined generally or do I miss a fact of Typo3..? How can I add an anchor link at the end of this "More >" href? Like:

> http://192.168.1.29/website/index.php?id=474&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=24&cHash=95d80a09fb9cbade7e934cda5e14e00a**#myAnchor1**

Answer (score 4):

`register:newsMoreLink` is not a function. It's one of the **[data types](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/2/)**. In other words a type of data that you can access with `stdWrap.data`. register is set with **[LOAD_REGISTER](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/7/#id2638922)**. Though, in case of tt_news this is set in the PHP code with `$this->local_cObj->LOAD_REGISTER()`.

I'm afraid you cannot easily add an anchor to that link. However, you can set the `append` to create your own custom link to the news record using **[typolink](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/5/#id2621840)**:

```
append = TEXT
append {
  value = text of the link
  typolink {
    # ...typolink configuration...
  }
}
```

You shall be interested in the typolink's attributes `parameter`, `additionalParams` and `section`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I use to link to an pid with a anchor target:

```
        displayList.plugin.tt_news.subheader_stdWrap {  

        append = TEXT
        append.data >
        append {
            value = mehr
            typolink{
                parameter = 47 // pid
                section  = entry_{field:uid} // anchor name
                section.insertData = 1
            }
        }
```